# Studying the nature of roots?

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, roots

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be real numbers. Then the fourth degree polynomial in $x,\boxed{ a c x^{4}+b(a+c) x^{3}+\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\right) x^{2}+b(a+c) x+ ac}$

(a) *Has four complex (non-real) roots*

(b) *Has either four real roots or four complex roots*

(c) *Has two real roots and two complex roots*

(d) *Has four real roots*

---

**My approach**

Let $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4$ be the roots of the equation:-

1)$t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4$= $\frac{-b(a+c)}{ac}$= real number

2)$t_1t_2+t_2t_3+t_3t_4+t_1t_3+t_1t_4+t_2t_4$=$\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ac}$)=real  number

**so (b) will be  the option**

Comment: Familiar with polynomial discriminant? Ahh, no. Divide by $x^2$ and let $t=x+\frac 1x$, $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=t^2-2$. That's the way. You'll be left with quadratic in $t$.

Comment: a nice way might be to look at easy examples like $b=0; a=c=1$ which has no real roots, and  $b=0; a=-c=1$ which has only real roots

Comment: How did you manage to note that? @WW1

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin clearly using vieta's relation well enough to found the eqs ,why substn is needed?

Comment: @Alexey Burdin One can say to the OP that this method will always work for the so-called [palindromic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_and_antipalindromic_polynomials) (another name being "self-reciprocal polynomials").